# Can possible to load only catalog/product/view.phtml in custom module

Tags: magento-1.9, module

I am trying to make a custom module for product quick view. Their only need to load *catalog/product/view.phtml*

Here is My code

*app\code\local\Abdus\Ajaxproduct\controllers\LoadproductController.php*

```
<?php
class Abdus_Ajaxproduct_LoadproductController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
    public function indexAction(){
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
    public function getbyskuAction(){
        $_prdSku    = $this->getRequest()->getParam('sku');
        $_product   = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('sku',$_prdSku);
        $this->productInfo($_product);
    }
    public function getbyidAction(){
        $_prdID     = intval($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));
        $_product   = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->load($prdID);
        $this->productInfo($_product);
    }
    public function productInfo($_product){
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

app\code\local\Abdus\Ajaxproduct\etc\config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Abdus_Ajaxproduct>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Abdus_Ajaxproduct>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <ajaxproduct>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Abdus_Ajaxproduct</module>
                    <frontName>ajaxproduct</frontName>
                </args>
            </ajaxproduct>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

*app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\local.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <ajaxproduct_loadproduct_getbysku>
        <remove name="head" />
        <remove name="header" />
        <remove name="footer" />
        <remove name="right" />
        <remove name="left" />
        <reference name="root">
            <block type="page/html" name="content" output="toHtml" template="catalog/product/view.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </ajaxproduct_loadproduct_getbysku>
</layout>
```

But when i call my link

*mysite/ajaxproduct/loadproduct/getbysku/sku/418*

Then I get a error

*Fatal error: Call to a member function getOptions() on null in D:\x\htdocs\m1\app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog\product\view.phtml on line 42*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incorrect block type.

Have a look at /frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml
You'll have to use this block nesting:
Take reference "content" instead of "root" and use correct block type.

```
 <reference name="content">
                <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">

...
```